# 3-pile Nim Game in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am building a Nim game in scheme that prompt users to enter the pile number and the number of items they want to remove. The computer will simply remove 1 from the first pile, if the first pile is empty, it will remove from 2nd pile, than 3rd.

My code won't work correctly, can someone please point out where I make mistakes? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
(define play-with-turns
  (lambda (game-state player)
    (display-game-state game-state)
    (cond ((over? game-state) 
           (announce-winner player))
          ((equal? player 'human)  
           (play-with-turns (human-move game-state) 'computer))
          ((equal? player 'computer)  
           (play-with-turns (computer-move game-state) 'human))
          (else  
           (error "player wasn't human or computer:" player)))))

(define computer-move
  (lambda (game-state)
    (let ((pile (if (> (size-of-pile game-state 1) 0)
                    1
                    2)))
      (display "I take 1 coin from pile ")
      (display pile)
      (newline)

      (remove-coins-from-pile game-state 1 pile))))

(define prompt
  (lambda (prompt-string)
    (newline)
    (display prompt-string)
    (newline)
    (read)))

(define human-move
  (lambda (game-state)
    (let ((p (prompt "Which pile will you remove from?")))
      (let ((n (prompt "How many coins do you want to remove?")))
        (remove-coins-from-pile game-state n p)))))

(define over?
  (lambda (game-state)
    (= (total-size game-state) 0)))

(define announce-winner
  (lambda (player)
    (if (equal? player 'human) 
        (display "You lose. Better luck next time.")
        (display "You win. Congratulations."))))

(define remove-coins-from-pile
  (lambda (game-state num-coins pile-number)
    (cond ((= pile-number 1)
           (make-game-state (- (size-of-pile game-state 1)
                               num-coins) 
                            (size-of-pile game-state 2)
                            (size-of-pile game-state 3)))
          ((= pile-number 2)
           (make-game-state (size-of-pile game-state 1)
                            (- (size-of-pile game-state 2)
                               num-coins)
                            (size-of-pile game-state 3)))
          ((= pile-number 3)
           (make-game-state (size-of-pile game-state 1)
                            (size-of-pile game-state 2)
                            (- (size-of-pile game-state 3)
                               num-coins))))))

(define exponent-of-in
  (lambda (n int)
    (if (= (remainder int n) 0)
        (+ 1 (exponent-of-in n (quotient int n)))
        0)))

(define make-game-state
  ;Returns a game state with n coins in the first pile
  ;m coins in the second pile, and k coins in the third pile.
  (lambda (n m k)
    (lambda (x)
      (cond ((= x 1) n)
            ((= x 2) m)
            ((= x 3) k)))))



(define size-of-pile
  ;Returns an integer equal to the number of coins in
  ;pile pile-number of the game-state.
  (lambda (game-state pile-number)
    (game-state pile-number)))

;; Utilities

(define display-game-state
  (lambda (game-state)
    (newline)
    (newline)
    (display "    Pile 1: ")
    (display (size-of-pile game-state 1))
    (newline)
    (display "    Pile 2: ")
    (display (size-of-pile game-state 2))
    (newline)
    (display "    Pile 3: ")
    (display (size-of-pile game-state 3))
    (newline)
    (newline)))

(define total-size
  (lambda (game-state)
    (+(+ (size-of-pile game-state 1)
         (size-of-pile game-state 2)) (size-of-pile game-state 3))))
```

Sample Output:

```
(play-with-turns (make-game-state 5 9 8) 'human)


    Pile 1: 5
    Pile 2: 9
    Pile 3: 8


Which pile will you remove from?
1

How many coins do you want to remove?
2


    Pile 1: 4
    Pile 2: 9
    Pile 3: 8

I take 1 coin from pile 1


    Pile 1: 3
    Pile 2: 9
    Pile 3: 8


Which pile will you remove from?
2

How many coins do you want to remove?
2


    Pile 1: 2
    Pile 2: 7
    Pile 3: 8

I take 1 coin from pile 1


    Pile 1: 1
    Pile 2: 7
    Pile 3: 8


Which pile will you remove from?
2

How many coins do you want to remove?
2


    Pile 1: 1
    Pile 2: 5
    Pile 3: 8

I take 1 coin from pile 1


    Pile 1: 0
    Pile 2: 5
    Pile 3: 8
```

Comment: It will help everyone if you describe exactly what your code is doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

First things first: I would strongly urge you to follow the Design Recipe, as outlined in [*How To Design Programs*](http://www.htdp.org/). First off, your functions could really use a one-line purpose statement each. Next, you really really need test cases for these functions. I strongly suspect that your `remove-coins-from-pile` function has a problem.

I see at least one bug in your code that you will catch easily with a good set of test cases. If you're using one of the student languages, you should be able to test by writing, e.g.:

```
(check-expect ((remove-coins-from-pile (make-game-state 3 9 7) 5 2) 3) 172)
```

please note that this test case is actually wrong; you'll have to fix it up.

If you were using the full #lang racket language, you would need to add

```
(require rackunit)
```

and then test using check-equal?:

```
(check-equal? ((remove-coins-from-pile (make-game-state 3 9 7) 5 2) 3) 172)
```

To be honest, someone has steered you toward a function-based approach (a game state is represented as a function) that makes testing much more difficult than it would be otherwise; if you had a "game-state" structure, you could test the whole game state at once by writing, e.g.,

```
(check-equal? (remove-coins-from-pile (make-game-state 3 9 7) 5 2)
              (make-game-state 17 27 0))
```

I'm guessing that this is an assignment from an instructor who really likes functions. Well, to be honest, *I* really like functions, but they don't go well
with testing in situations like this.

For more details, I would refer you again to the *How To Design Programs* text.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I'm very new to computer science and scheme. Could you please point out what is the problem in  remove-coins-from-pile ? I can't tell where should be fixed. I don't even know to to write test cases. I test my program by running it and input numbers every time.

Comment: Yikes! That's an exhausting and imprecise way of testing. I've edited my answer above to provide more details.